# C# IO exception the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: c#, .net

Sometimes my application throws an exception saying that the file is corrupted or unredable. Basically this file is a log file. My Application writes events and some data to the log file.

My Application was put on to Embedded box in which Windows XP OS runs.The only way to close the application is to shutoff power to the embeeded box. Since windows is not shutdown gracefully, the file is corrupted sometimes(this is what i am thinking).

I am using Intel SSD as a drive.I have enabled write caching on the disk. Does this cause the file corruption?

If i capture the exception, then can I delete this file using c# file functions(file.delete)?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Write caching doesn't cause file corruption. Shutting the machine off while the file is open causes the file corruption.

If you capture the exception then you should be able to delete the file.

You can probably lessen the frequency of errors if you call `Flush` on the log file whenever you write to it. You can almost completely eliminate the error if you close the file after every write (which, of course, would require that you open it for append before every write). That might be prohibitively expensive.

You can't *completely* eliminate the error as long as the only way to shut down the application is to remove power. You might consider rotating the log, though, so if it does get corrupted you only lose the last hour (or 15 minutes, or whatever amount of time you use for your log rotate frequency).

Comment: in addition to Jim's remark on shutting down when a file is open, you should look up File Handlers.